# Remove select2 border on active of select element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-select2

I have gone through its css code but not able to find its actually property that is being applied on the main element.

i'm making some changes in select2 library so that i can use it in my way. i trapped in its CSS did not get from which property border displayed on active or focus on element.

Did not find any `:active` `selector` in `css` or I also checked it in `js` file not also there,while debugging not showing any css applied on that element.

[Link for plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0WQ2yDefH3Zr30Zjf5H5?p=preview)

**image of element border.**

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Resolved**

```
span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single {
        outline: none;
    }
```

[updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eep4PqlpIobbshVaOBIW?p=preview)