# How can I remove blue border from Select2 dropdown menu options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I want remove the blue box coming in the Select2 dropdown menu. This is a multiple section box.

[image]

```
<select class= "form-control select2" id="print" multiple= "multiple">
```

```js
$(".select2").select2({
    width:"100%",
    allowClear: true,
    tag: false, 
    placeholder: "Select"
});
```

What I am doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: That looks like a CSS related problem. Right click the element in your browser and inspect it. Check the CSS rules on the element for a `border` rule, and then find what file and line its on. Then you can just amend/remove that line of CSS code.

Comment: similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413051/remove-select2-border-on-active-of-select-element

Comment: You should change in css, if i sit front of my computer then i can share with you which class should be changed

Answer (score -1):

Add this code too correct css to remove it:

```
border: "none";
```

I think it should go here:

```
$(".select2").select2({
    width:"100%",
    border: "none",
    allowClear: true,
    tag: false, 
    placeholder: "Select"
});
```